# Is it possible to use placeholder with db triggers

Tags: spring, oracle, jpa, triggers, spring-data

I just wanted to know whether we can use place holder in db triggers.
I have two tables named

IMPL_USER,
IMPL_DETAILS

I want to write trigger which should trigger before insert to any one of the above tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER before_insert_user
BEFORE INSERT
   ON IMPL_**      -- placeholder like this??????
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_username varchar2(10);

BEGIN

//--- some code

END;
```

I don't want to write 2 separate triggers (Since I have more than 20 tables). I am using spring boot, spring data JPA with ORACLE data base.

Can some one please let me know whether its possible to do like this?? If not what are all the available options?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, you can't do this. A trigger belongs to a specific table; you can't write a trigger that acts on more than one table - unless you have a view and you create an instead-of trigger.

Comment: @Boneist: Thanks for the comment. Could you please provide piece of code where I can develop on top of that?

Comment: [This should help](http://goo.gl/ayiRRO)

Comment: Thank for the answer :) 
One last question, Does it make sense to create view by combining more than 20 rows???

Comment: 20 rows? Did you mean tables? It entirely depends on what the purpose of the view is supposed to do. Does it give any business benefit, or is it something you're thinking of doing in order to avoid having to write a few triggers? In my experience, it's often easier to go the simple route and simply write all the triggers (or column names or ...) individually, rather than trying to be clever and minimise the amount of code you're trying to write. That way often leads to madness and overly complicated code that's a PITA to maintain! Do you really need a trigger at all? What's it going to do?

Comment: Sorry, yes 20 tables.....My requirement is , if any thing changes on db side( any table(update/delete/insert)) I need to send push notification to UI. So I am thinking best possible way.

Comment: You know that Oracle allows you to register for notifications already before you go and re-invent your own technology? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_cqn.htm#CHDEFIFJ